# Printing the result of operations on integers and floats

Tags: c

Consider the following C-program:

```
int main() {
    int a =2;
    float b = 2;
    float c = 3;
    int d = 3;
    printf("%d %f %d %f %d %f %d %f\n", a/c, a/c, a/d, a/d, b/c, b/c, b/d, b/d);
    printf("%d\n", a/c);
}
```

The output of this is:

```
 0 0.666667 0 0.666667 2 0.666667 0 0.666667
 539648
```

I can't make sense of this at all. Why does printing a/c as an integer give 0, while b/c gives 2? Aren't all integers promoted to floats in computations involving both floats and integers? So the answer should be 0 in both cases.

In the second line of the output I'm simply printing a/c as an integer, which gives a garbage value for some reason (even though it gives 0 when I print it in the first compound printf statement). Why is this happening?

Comment: `a/c` is a `float` and printing a `float` with the `%d` format specifier is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Gerard  This indeed does not make sense because has undefined behavior.:)

Comment: I think I should start writing that canonical duplicate community wiki for "the usual arithmetic conversions". We need one and I can't find any good dupes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour:

```
printf("%d %f %d %f %d %f %d %f\n", a/c, a/c, a/d, a/d, b/c, b/c, b/d, b/d);
```

The format specifier for `printf` must match the type of the provided parameter. As `printf` doesn't provide a parameter list with types, but only `...` there is no implicit type conversion apart from standard type conversion.

If you have UB, basically anything can happen.

What is likely to happen is the following:

Depending on the format specifier, `printf` consumes a certain number of bytes from the calling parameters. This number of bytes matches the specified format type. If the number of bytes does not match the number of bytes passed as an argument, you are out of sync for all successive parameters.
And of course you do incorrect interpretation of the data.

Comment: Is it possible to explain why the value of a/c (when printed as an integer) in the first printf statement consistently gives 2?

Comment: Without a prototype floating point values are converted to `double`. I assume that an `int` takes 4 bytes, while a `double` takes 8 bytes. As mentioned the number of bytes need to match which doesn't seem to be the case and you are probably looking at some other bytes than what you expect. I don't know which values are stored in the 8 bytes to hold the `double` result.  You need to check the memory contents and take the first 4 bytes.

Comment: As this all is UB, it doesn't make much sense to elaborate why it fails in a certain way. Instead you should fix the UB.

Answer (score 1):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

If you have for example the following declarations

```
int a =2;
float c = 3;
```

and then call the function `printf` the following way

```
printf( "%d", a / c );
```

then behind the hood the following events occur.

The expression `a / c` has the type `float` due to *the usual arithmetic conversions*.

As the function `printf` is declared with the ellipsis notation then to the expression `a / c` of the type `float` there are applied *the default argument promotions*  that convert the expression to the type `double`.

As result in this call there is an attempt to output an expression of the type `double` using conversion specifier `%d` designed for the type `int`.  Hanse   the call has undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.275) **If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**